How to Track Token Buy/Sell Transactions for a Wallet via an API
I am working on a project where I need to monitor when a specific wallet buys or sells tokens. While I am familiar with using getAccountInfo to obtain information about what an account currently holds, I haven't found a way to specifically track transactions related to buying or selling tokens.
Could anyone suggest an API or a method that allows tracking these specific types of transactions? Any pointers on the relevant API methods or instructions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

u can use websockets and subscribe to an account
https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/accountsubscribe
an example from solana cookbook
import asyncio
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solana.rpc.websocket_api import connect

async def main():
    async with connect("wss://api.devnet.solana.com") as websocket:
        # Create a Test Wallet
        wallet = Keypair()
        # Subscribe to the Test wallet to listen for events
        await websocket.account_subscribe(wallet.pubkey())
        # Capture response from account subscription 
        first_resp = await websocket.recv()
        print("Subscription successful with id {}, listening for events \n".format(first_resp.result))
        updated_account_info = await websocket.recv()
        print(updated_account_info)
        
asyncio.run(main())

seems the resp is a dictionary in a list so i adapted the above code to work with this structure
import asyncio
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solana.rpc.websocket_api import connect


async def main():
    async with connect("wss://api.devnet.solana.com") as websocket:
        # Create a Test Wallet
        wallet = Keypair()
        # Subscribe to the Test wallet to listen for events
        await websocket.account_subscribe(wallet.pubkey())
        # Capture response from account subscription
        first_resp = await websocket.recv()
        result_value = first_resp[0].result
        print(f"Subscription successful with id {result_value}, listening for events\n")
        updated_account_info = await websocket.recv()
        print(updated_account_info)


asyncio.run(main())

